# What makes Victor stronger than pre-adamantium Wolverine?

Tags: marvel, x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, wolverine, x-men-origins-wolverine

In Wolverine Origins, [Stryker convinces Wolverine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b3vNYkINs90) that he needs his help to defeat Victor, a.k.a, Sabertooth.

However, we also know that the only reason Victor is not offered adamantium is that his healing factor is not as strong as Wolverine's.

My question is, other than Stryker's testimony, is there any canon evidence proving that Victor is definitely stronger than pre-adamantium Wolverine? If there is, in what ways Victor is stronger?

Comment: healing factor != strength

Comment: @OrangeDog I know. That is why I am asking if there is a canon evidence for strength, stamina, agility or any other physical trait superiority.

Comment: The fact that Victor can beat Wolverine in a fight seems like decent evidence.

Comment: Are you asking for evidence solely surrounding the X-Men Origins: Wolverine movie or will evidence from the comics or animated series work as well?

Comment: @Gothamite24 actually yes, any x-men franchise is included. Due to some unhelpful edit, the x-men tag was removed. let me add the tag again.

Comment: Let me research this a bit, I'll get back to you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pre - Adamantium Wolverine and Sabertooth have practically the same powers and abilities, with Wolverine having a slightly better healing factor. So, in a fight between them, the outcome would come down to brute strength and fighting ability.

Wolverine stands at 5'3" and weighs 195 pounds without Adamantium as shown on [Wolverine's data from the official Marvel website](http://marvel.com/characters/66/wolverine). Sabretooth, on the other hand, towers over him at a height of 6'6" with a weight of 275 pounds as shown on [Sabretooth's data from the Marvel website](https://marvel.com/universe/Sabretooth). His physical attributes itself put him at a huge advantage over Wolverine.

The height, however, can be overcome by fighting ability. With proper training, Wolverine could have still won at his disadvantaged height. But here, at this point in the movie, both Sabretooth and Wolverine have minimal professional training. Moreover, Sabretooth proves to have more animal-like instincts and a raw bloodthirst, that may help him make the quick decisions necessary in a fight. Hence, without the Adamantium it can be speculated that Wolverine could not have beaten Sabretooth and shows Sabretooth's physical superiority over Wolverine.

Comment: Welcome to SFF! This is a decent first answer but I'd like to point out that fighting is not all about height and weight. For example, a well trained fighter is taught how to use an opponents height/weight against them so it could have put Sabertooth at a disadvantage.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Thank you for your edits and input. I have changed the answer based on the point you have mentioned.

Comment: Them both being veterans of numerous wars, I imagine they got some bit of professional training.

Comment: @Worse_Username Professional training yes, But I don't think Logan received training involving how he could use his size to his advantage. I would assume it would be training on weapon use and basic fighting, not specialized. But that is up to speculation.

Comment: Although this is a very good answer (a great answer for the first answer), I am looking for confrontations between sabertooth and wolverine on any x-men franchise. You have my upvote, but I will not award the bounty.

Comment: Well, the bounty is about to expire, so I'll give it to you anyway. Thanks!